# How do i hide seams after splitting the mesh in 3DS Max

Tags: 3dsmax, edges, normals

How do i hide seams after splitting the mesh in 3DS Max? I have to split the mesh in order to the rig the mesh as there is a bone limit of 20 for each mesh for the rig to work in game. The problem I face is that after i split the mesh, the seams are visible in game.
3DS Max Preview (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyUKB.png)In Game Preview (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQfHt.jpg)

I used Noors Normal thief addon and the Ornatrix Normal transfer plugin, but still the seams are visible in game.